# Derivative of a function with hyperbolic cosine and exponent $\frac{e^{4x}}{x^3 \cosh (2x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions

I have an assignment in which I have to differentiate a function that employs both exponential and hyperbolic trig parts. The equation is:

$$
y=\frac{e^{4x}}{x^3 \cosh (2x)}
$$

I know I need to use a combination of Quotient Rule, Chain Rule and Product Rule, and i get as far as

$$
y'=\frac{e^{4x} [x\cosh(2x)-2 \cosh⁡(2x)-2x \sinh(2x)]}{x^4\cosh^2(2x)}
$$

I don't even know if what I have done so far is correct.

I know I can use Logarithmic Differentiation for this problem as well, but I don't get anywhere near the required answer using it, so some advice on that would be awesome too.

---

The answer I need to get is

$$
y'=\frac{e^{4x} [(4x-3)\cosh(2x)+2x\sinh(2x)]}{x^4}
$$

I have no idea where the $(4x-3)$ comes from, or where the $\cosh^2(2x)$ disappears to from the denominator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logarithmic differentiation seems like a good plan; anything to avoid a combined quotient and product rule.

$$
\ln(y) = 4x - 3 \ln x - \ln[\cosh(2x)]\\
\frac{y'}{y} = 4 - \frac 3x - \frac{2\sinh(2x)}{\cosh(2x)} = \frac{4 x \cosh(2x) - 3 \cosh(2x) - 2x \sinh(2x)}{x \cosh(2x)} =\\
\frac{(4x - 3)\cosh(2x) - 2x \sinh(2x)}{x \cosh(2x)}
$$
So, the answer we should end up with is
$$
y' = \frac{e^{4x}[(4x - 3)\cosh(2x) - 2x \sinh(2x)]}{x^4 \cosh^2(2x)}
$$
It seems that they have erroneously left out the $\cosh^2(2x)$ in the denominator.

Your mistake in differentiating is that you forgot to apply the chain rule when differentiating $e^{4x}$.

Comment: Thank you. I retried and got it. Awesome answer. Wish I could give more than one upvote.